# android log printing error

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm running an Android app which downloads information from a website and prints a list on-screen with that information.

However, when it's trying to load the list, the app crashes and I get the following logcat:

```
  04-15 23:32:41.946: I/Choreographer(2069): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-15 23:32:50.038: I/Choreographer(2069): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-15 23:32:52.096: I/DO IN BACKGROUD(2069): {"succeed":true,"user_id":362}
04-15 23:32:52.096: I/MESSAGE(2069): {"succeed":true,"user_id":362}
04-15 23:32:52.146: I/put Extra user id(2069): 362
04-15 23:32:56.256: I/dalvikvm-heap(2069): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.554MB for 635812-byte allocation
04-15 23:32:59.027: I/Connection(2069): true
04-15 23:32:59.257: I/Choreographer(2069): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-15 23:33:00.456: I/Choreographer(2069): Skipped 297 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-15 23:33:01.447: I/Choreographer(2069): Skipped 229 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-15 23:33:03.138: I/Choreographer(2069): Skipped 184 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-15 23:33:03.856: I/Choreographer(2069): Skipped 186 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-15 23:33:04.349: I/DO IN BACKGROUD(2069): {  "supermercado": "La Salle - Curs Android II",   "productos" : [     {           "id" : 1,           "fabricante" : "Nestlé",            "nombre" : "NESQUIK",           "precio" : 12.85,           "stock" : 10        },      {           "id" : 2,           "fabricante" : "Coca-cola",         "nombre" : "Coca-cola",         "precio" : 3.21,            "stock" : 150       },      {           "id" : 3,           "fabricante" : "Borges",            "nombre" : "Aceite girasol 1L",         "precio" : 1.88,            "stock" : 0     },      {           "id" : 4,           "fabricante" : "Serpis",            "nombre" : "Aceitunas rellenas de anchoa 160g",         "precio" : 1.39,            "stock" : 1523      },      {           "id" : 5,           "fabricante" : "Carretilla",            "nombre" : "Pimientos piquillo ajillo 290g",            "precio" : 2.25,            "stock" : 14        },      {           "id" : 6,           "fabricante" : "Orlando",           "nombre" : "Tomate frito con aceite de oliva virgen brik 390g",         "precio" : 0.95,            "stock" : 0     },      {           "id" : 7,           "fabricante" : "Kellogg's",         "nombre" : "Cereales Special K chocolate 300g",         "precio" : 2.39,            "stock" : 152       },      {           "id" : 8,           "fabricante" : "Lu",            "nombre" : "Galletas rellenas mini Principe 160g",          "precio" : 1.59,            "stock" : 29        },      {           "id" : 9,           "fabricante" : "Pascual",           "nombre" : "Leche sin lactosa desnatada brik 1l",           "precio" : 1.49,            "stock" : 1596      },      {           "id" : 10,          "fabricante" : "Danone",            "nombre" : "Danet vainilla 4x125g",         "precio" : 1.90,            "stock" : 856       },      {           "id" : 11,          "fabricante" : "Hornimans",         "nombre" : "Infusueños 20 sobres",          "precio" : 2.35,            "stock" : 598       }   ]}
04-15 23:33:04.516: I/Choreographer(2069): Skipped 169 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-15 23:33:04.848: I/Choreographer(2069): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-15 23:33:05.188: I/On Post EXECUTE(2069): {  "supermercado": "La Salle - Curs Android II",   "productos" : [     {           "id" : 1,           "fabricante" : "Nestlé",            "nombre" : "NESQUIK",           "precio" : 12.85,           "stock" : 10        },      {           "id" : 2,           "fabricante" : "Coca-cola",         "nombre" : "Coca-cola",         "precio" : 3.21,            "stock" : 150       },      {           "id" : 3,           "fabricante" : "Borges",            "nombre" : "Aceite girasol 1L",         "precio" : 1.88,            "stock" : 0     },      {           "id" : 4,           "fabricante" : "Serpis",            "nombre" : "Aceitunas rellenas de anchoa 160g",         "precio" : 1.39,            "stock" : 1523      },      {           "id" : 5,           "fabricante" : "Carretilla",            "nombre" : "Pimientos piquillo ajillo 290g",            "precio" : 2.25,            "stock" : 14        },      {           "id" : 6,           "fabricante" : "Orlando",           "nombre" : "Tomate frito con aceite de oliva virgen brik 390g",         "precio" : 0.95,            "stock" : 0     },      {           "id" : 7,           "fabricante" : "Kellogg's",         "nombre" : "Cereales Special K chocolate 300g",         "precio" : 2.39,            "stock" : 152       },      {           "id" : 8,           "fabricante" : "Lu",            "nombre" : "Galletas rellenas mini Principe 160g",          "precio" : 1.59,            "stock" : 29        },      {           "id" : 9,           "fabricante" : "Pascual",           "nombre" : "Leche sin lactosa desnatada brik 1l",           "precio" : 1.49,            "stock" : 1596      },      {           "id" : 10,          "fabricante" : "Danone",            "nombre" : "Danet vainilla 4x125g",         "precio" : 1.90,            "stock" : 856       },      {           "id" : 11,          "fabricante" : "Hornimans",         "nombre" : "Infusueños 20 sobres",          "precio" : 2.35,            "stock" : 598       }   ]}
04-15 23:33:05.486: I/Write STORAGE(2069): {    "supermercado": "La Salle - Curs Android II",   "productos" : [     {           "id" : 1,           "fabricante" : "Nestlé",            "nombre" : "NESQUIK",           "precio" : 12.85,           "stock" : 10        },      {           "id" : 2,           "fabricante" : "Coca-cola",         "nombre" : "Coca-cola",         "precio" : 3.21,            "stock" : 150       },      {           "id" : 3,           "fabricante" : "Borges",            "nombre" : "Aceite girasol 1L",         "precio" : 1.88,            "stock" : 0     },      {           "id" : 4,           "fabricante" : "Serpis",            "nombre" : "Aceitunas rellenas de anchoa 160g",         "precio" : 1.39,            "stock" : 1523      },      {           "id" : 5,           "fabricante" : "Carretilla",            "nombre" : "Pimientos piquillo ajillo 290g",            "precio" : 2.25,            "stock" : 14        },      {           "id" : 6,           "fabricante" : "Orlando",           "nombre" : "Tomate frito con aceite de oliva virgen brik 390g",         "precio" : 0.95,            "stock" : 0     },      {           "id" : 7,           "fabricante" : "Kellogg's",         "nombre" : "Cereales Special K chocolate 300g",         "precio" : 2.39,            "stock" : 152       },      {           "id" : 8,           "fabricante" : "Lu",            "nombre" : "Galletas rellenas mini Principe 160g",          "precio" : 1.59,            "stock" : 29        },      {           "id" : 9,           "fabricante" : "Pascual",           "nombre" : "Leche sin lactosa desnatada brik 1l",           "precio" : 1.49,            "stock" : 1596      },      {           "id" : 10,          "fabricante" : "Danone",            "nombre" : "Danet vainilla 4x125g",         "precio" : 1.90,            "stock" : 856       },      {           "id" : 11,          "fabricante" : "Hornimans",         "nombre" : "Infusueños 20 sobres",          "precio" : 2.35,            "stock" : 598       }   ]}
04-15 23:33:07.027: W/dalvikvm(2069): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at com.example.shop.Tenda.refreshListByJson(Tenda.java:305)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at com.example.shop.Tenda.access$1(Tenda.java:302)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at com.example.shop.Tenda$LongAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Tenda.java:259)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at com.example.shop.Tenda$LongAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Tenda.java:1)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-15 23:33:07.266: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 23:33:13.366: I/Process(2069): Sending signal. PID: 2069 SIG: 9
04-15 23:33:20.867: I/Choreographer(2098): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Here's the activity where the crash happens:

**Tenda.java**

```
package com.example.shop;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.shop.SuperAdapter;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Tenda extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, LocationListener {

    ProgressDialog lDialog;
    String json_string;
    SuperAdapter adapter_super;
    int user_id;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    public String provider;
    private String  lattitude , longitude; 

    /*************************************************/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tenda);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        init_conf();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tenda, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_update:
                updateList();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_search:
                alert_search();
                return true;   
            case R.id.menu_cancel:
                finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {

        TextView stock = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_stock);
        int num_stock = Integer.parseInt(stock.getText().toString()) ; 

        if(num_stock!=0){
            ArrayList<Super> productes=adapter_super.getItems_producte();
            Super current_product= productes.get(position);

            alert_buy(num_stock,current_product);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "OUT OF STOCK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void init_conf(){

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        user_id = extras.getInt("user_id");

        Toast.makeText(this, "user id"+Integer.toString(user_id), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ListView lsv_producto = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_productes);
        adapter_super = new SuperAdapter(Tenda.this,null);
        lsv_producto.setAdapter(adapter_super);
        lsv_producto.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        updateList();

    }

    private void updateList(){
        loading();
        String url = "http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-android/products.php?user_id="+user_id;

        boolean is_con=is_connected();

        if(is_con){
            Log.i("Connection", "true");
            AsyncTask(url);
            Toast.makeText(this, "connected internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            json_string=storeRead();
            refreshListByJson(json_string);
            Toast.makeText(this, "not connected internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void search(String text){
        loading();
        String url="http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-android/search.php?user_id="+user_id+"&q="+text;

        boolean is_con=is_connected();
        if(is_con){
            Log.i("search URL", url);
            Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            searchAsyncTask(url);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "NO CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

private void buy(Super producte, int value){

        int product_id=  producte.getId();

        String url="http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-android/buy.php?user_id="+user_id+
                    "&product_id="+product_id+
                    "&items="+value+
                    "&lat="+1+
                    "&long="+1;

        Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private void AsyncTask(String url){
        LongAsyncTask task = new LongAsyncTask();
        task.execute(url);
    }

    private void searchAsyncTask(String url){
        SearchAsyncTask task = new SearchAsyncTask();
        task.execute(url);
    }

    public void alert_search(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), m_Text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                search(m_Text);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }

    public void alert_buy(int max_value,final Super producte){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("BUY");

        final NumberPicker number= new NumberPicker(this);
        number.setMaxValue(max_value);
        number.setMinValue(0);
        builder.setView(number);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int value= number.getValue();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                buy(producte,value);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }

    /*************************ASYNC TASK************************/

    public class LongAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String url_result= conect(url[0]);
            Log.i("DO IN BACKGROUND", url_result);
            return url_result;

        }
       protected void onPostExecute(String url_result) {
           Log.i("On Post EXECUTE", url_result);
           json_string= url_result;
           storeWrite(json_string);
           refreshListByJson(json_string);//line 259
       }

    }

        public class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String url_result= conect(url[0]);
            Log.i("Search result", url_result);
            return url_result;

        }

       protected void onPostExecute(String url_result) {
           Log.i("On Post EXECUTE SEARCH", url_result);
           json_string= url_result;
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           refreshListByJson(json_string);
       }

    }

    public class BuyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String url_result= conect(url[0]);
            Log.i("buy result", url_result);
            return url_result;

        }
       protected void onPostExecute(String url_result) {
           Log.i("On Post EXECUTE SEARCH", url_result);
           json_string= url_result;
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

    }

    /*************************************************/

    private void refreshListByJson(String json){//line 302
        lDialog.dismiss();
       Store store=Store.newStore(json);
           Log.i("store-nom", store.getStore());//line 305
           Log.i("store-producte", store.getProductos().toString());
           adapter_super.setItems_producto(store.getProductos());    
    }

    private void storeWrite(String data){
        String FILENAME = "json_store";

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("Write STORAGE", data);

    }

    private String storeRead(){
        String FILENAME = "json_store";

        FileInputStream  fis;
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            fis= openFileInput (FILENAME);
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
            {
                fileContent.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            fis.close();
            Log.i("READ STORAGE", fileContent.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fileContent.toString();
    }

    public String conect(String url_string){

        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        BufferedReader reader= null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(url_string);
            con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String line ="";
            StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                responseBuffer.append(line);
            }

            return responseBuffer.toString(); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage(),ex);
            return  null;
        }

    }

    public boolean is_connected(){
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          if (i == null)
            return false;
          if (!i.isConnected())
            return false;
          if (!i.isAvailable())
            return false;
          return true;
    }

    private void loading(){
         lDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
         lDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
         lDialog.setCancelable(false);
         lDialog.show();
    }


/*** Location ***/

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int lat = (int) (arg0.getLatitude());
int lng = (int) (arg0.getLongitude());
lattitude = "Lattitude: "+ lat ;
longitude = "Longitude: "+ lng; 
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
////TODO Auto-generated method stub

}               

}
```

And the classes:

**SuperAdapter**

```
package com.example.shop;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.shop.Super;
import com.example.shop.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SuperAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    public ArrayList<Super> getItems_producte() {
        return items_producte;
    }

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Super> items_producte;

    public SuperAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Super> items_producte){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items_producte= items_producte;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(items_producte==null){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return items_producte.size();
        }   }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items_producte.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup Parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = contentView;

        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflate =(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.info_product, null,false);
        }

        Super item_producto = items_producte.get(position);

        TextView id = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_id);
        TextView fabricant = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_fabricant);
        TextView nom = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_nom);
        TextView preu = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_preu);
        TextView stock = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_product_stock);

        id.setText(Integer.toString(item_producto.getId()));
        fabricant.setText(item_producto.getFabricant());
        nom.setText(item_producto.getNom());
        preu.setText(Float.toString(item_producto.getPreu()));
        stock.setText(Integer.toString(item_producto.getStock()));

        fabricant.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.fabricant));
        nom.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.fabricant));
        preu.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.fabricant));
        stock.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.fabricant));

        if(position%2==0){
            view.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.files_parelles));

        }
        else{
            view.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.files_imparelles));
        }

        /*STOKE COLOR*/
        if(item_producto.getStock()<=0){
            view.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_bg));

            fabricant.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_tx));
            nom.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_tx));
            preu.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_tx));
            stock.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.stock_null_tx));

        }


        return view;
    }


    public void setItems_producto(ArrayList<Super> items_producto) {
        this.items_producte = items_producto;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}

**LongAsyncTask**

    package com.example.shop;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    public class LongAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            return null;
        }


       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

       }

    }
```

**Store.java**

```
    package com.example.shop;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Store {

    private String store;
    private ArrayList<Super> productes;

    public String getStore() {
        return store;
    }
    public void setSupermercado(String store) {
        this.store = store;
    }
    public ArrayList<Super> getProductos() {
        return productes;
    }
    public void setProductes(ArrayList<Super> productes) {
        this.productes = productes;
    }

    static Store newStore(String json_string){

        Gson gson= new Gson();

        Store store = gson.fromJson(json_string,Store.class);

        return store;

    }


}
```

**Super.java**

```
package com.example.shop;

public class Super {

    private int id;
    private String fabricant;
    private String nom;
    private float preu;
    private int stock;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFabricant() {
        return fabricant;
    }
    public void setFabricant(String fabricant) {
        this.fabricant = fabricant;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public float getPreu() {
        return preu;
    }
    public void setPreu(float preu) {
        this.preu = preu;
    }
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

}
```

**LongAsyncTask.java**

```
package com.example.shop;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class LongAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        return null;
    }


   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   }

}
```

Could anyone help me understand what the mistake is? I built this app based on a very similar app which did work but mine crashes when it tries to print on-screen the list.

I checked all of the classes as well and I don't see any problem with the function-calling from one to another and such: I'm really stuck on this one.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `Logcat` you got a `NullPointerException` at :

```
com.example.shop.Tenda.refreshListByJson(Tenda.java:305)
```

At this line :

```
Log.i("store-nom", store.getStore());//line 305
```

It implies that `store.getStore()` returns `null`. You must provide a non `null` `String` to `Log`.

You can try to print like that :

```
Log.i("store-nom", "" + store.getStore());
```

Or just be sure that `store.getStore()` isn't `null`.

Comment: A big part of the issue here is that the tag field is being misused.  The tag field should designate the component which is doing the logging, while the designation of what is logged should be in the message field, along with the value.  When that is done, the message field will never be null.  Ie, Log.d("MyActivity", "the value is " + value);

Comment: @giant00: I tried applying this correction you suggested to both "log.i" lines and the type of error has changed: now I get nullPointerException in "private void refreshListByJson(String json)" and "Log.i("store-producte", "" + store.getProductos().toString());". One of the messages is "at com.example.shop.Tenda.access$1(Tenda.java:300)".

Comment: @user3082271 Can you check if `store.getProductos()` is `null` ?

Comment: Using a log.i or something like that, you mean? getProductos() is created in the class Store.java as "public ArrayList<Super> getProductos()", returns "productes" and "productes" and is defined as "private ArrayList<Super> productes;". Doesn't this mean that it's loaded with the info of class "Super.java"?

Comment: @user3082271: You can add a simple `if (store.getProductos() != null)` above the `Log`. I don't see in your code where you call the setter for `private ArrayList<Super> productes;`. So the `ArrayList` must be uninitialized.

Comment: Certainly looks like it: when I add the "if" the app screen remains blank and nothing is loaded even when I use the "update" and "search" functions.

Comment: The setter is in "Store.java": public void setProductes (ArrayList <Super> productes) { this.productes = productes; }

Comment: @user3082271 I saw the setter but i don't see where you call it. Add some data in your `ArrayList` and be sure it goes in `adapter_super.setItems_producto(store.getProductos());`.

Comment: But the data which will be displayed in the ArrayList is downloaded from a website: what I do is to build the structure to display it and name its values (i.e., name, maker, price...).

Comment: @user3082271: You can just fill the `ArrayList` with some trivial hard coded value. You will see if it displays correctly.